# Realm version working with RN 0.45

Tags: react-native, realm

Is there currently a Realm version which works with RN v0.45 ?
I don't want to downgrade however would like to start working on Realm implementation in my project.

Comment: realm-js 1.8.0 should work with React Native 0.45

Comment: latest is 1.3.1, not sure why in npm they called it 1.8, in any case - thats the one which doesnt work, I wonder if older versions are any good

Comment: I'm pretty sure 1.8 is the latest realm-js version. Could you please try installing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realm for React Native 0.45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637528/realm-for-react-native-0-45)