# Realm for React Native 0.45

Tags: react-native, realm

I read on the official [docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) of Realm for React Native that the Realm is not compatible for RN 0.45. What shall I do where downgrading RN is not an option?

Comment: realm-js 1.8.0 which was released the other day is compatible with React Native 0.45 - the docs are outdated.

Comment: Hey thanks for mentioning that.  @Tayschrenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[realm-js v1.8.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#180-release-notes-2017-6-15) added support for versions of React Native that use the C++ JavaScript bridge.